# iOS - pasted text in cordova appears smaller

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, webview

We're having a strange iOS only bug. If you write in an input the text appears completely normals, however when being pasted it's smaller. Maybe it's important to add that the field is not an input, but rather a `div` with `contenteditable="true"`.

Does iOS apply / remove some additional information when copying or pasting? The text was copied out of the very input it was pasted to again. Any hints are appreciated.

Edit: Here's the HTML after pasting some text. It actually adds a span with some style information, so can this be turned off?

```
<div id="title" contenteditable="true">
  Not pasted text
  <span style="font-size: 12px; white-space: normal; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0);">pasted text</span>
</div>
```

[image: Expample]

Answer (score -1):

Try not having

```
font-size: 12px;
```

in your span. Or if you have to have it, try using

```
font-size: 100%;
```